# How to put a comment in a .list file?

Tags: software-sources

How to put a comment in a .list file?

I'm accessing my sources.list Repositories to check if there are required amount of Repositories or not. There a can see a line which starts with `#` and i got a feeling like it's a comment so I asked this question.

Comment: It is a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Came here after inputing "debian .list file comment" in my favorite search engine, might happen to someone else.
It *is*, indeed, a comment.

From [Debian manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.en.html):

> Empty lines are ignored, and a # character anywhere on a line marks the remainder of that line as a comment.